# Installing CodeDOM providers with command line

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I am trying to install "CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")". I have downloaded the command line executable from here : https://dist.nuget.org/index.html
But when I launch it, it opens, writes something and instantly closes.
I do not have time to write any command to install a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nuget.exe is a command line application. If you open a command prompt or terminal window and run nuget.exe it will show you help information about supported commands.

The commands for nuget.exe are also [documented](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference) on the nuget.org web site.

To download a NuGet package using nuget.exe you run:

```
nuget install PackageId
```

Replacing the PackageId with the id of the NuGet package you want. In your case it should be something like:

```
nuget install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```